# dpkg-buildpackage -b gives error

Tags: software-installation

Running the command `dpkg-buildpackage -b` on server while installing `brotli`  gives the following error:

```
make: *** [config.status.core] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - the `brotli` package is [available in *universe* pocket of official repositories since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=brotli).

But if you really need to build deb-package from sources on 14.04 LTS you should:

1. Enable source code repositories from *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and then reload repository information.
2. Get build dependencies for the package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install autotools-dev build-essential cmake cmake-data debhelper \
   g++ gettext intltool-debian \
   libarchive-zip-perl libexpat1-dev \
   libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev libpython3-dev \
   libstdc++-4.8-dev libunistring0 po-debconf python-dev python-setuptools \
   python2.7-dev python3-dev python3-setuptools python3.5-dev
   ```
3. Install Debian package development tools and git with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev git
   ```
4. Get package with source code from official repository

   ```
   git clone https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brotli
   ```
5. Change directory to the downloaded source code and checkout 16.04 LTS version

   ```
   cd brotli
   git checkout ubuntu/xenial-updates
   ```
6. Build binary package

   ```
   dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc -us
   ```

   skipping signing the package (see [`man dpkg-buildpackage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html)):

   > `-us` *Do not sign the source package.*
   >   `-uc` *Do not sign the .changes file.*
7. Finally install created deb-packages with

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ../*brotli*.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f # to make sure that all dependencies satisfied
   ```
8. Enjoy

   ```
   $ brotli --version
   brotli 1.0.4
   ```

Note: the error may be caused by not enough free memory - it fails on VM with 1 Gb of RAN.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i am using ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Can i use the above steps for it ?

Comment: Updated and tested answer for 14.04 LTS. Check it and accept and/or vote for it :)